# google cloud engine instance is deleting installed packages

Tags: installation, instance, google-cloud-platform

i am running a google cloud compute instance as a debian jessie machine.
i installed apache and java via apt-get and tomcat via wget from the tomcat repository.
the instance is running and not stopped.
ever since i installed the packages, i notice that at one point, some of the features i installed are removed.
in tomcat, the manager directory is deleted and with it the capability to remote manage the server via the web interface.
also, a WAR i deployed is also deleted.
why is this happening?
i need to constantly remove and re-install the tomcat and re-deploy the WAR file.

is this something related to a snapshot i took of the instance? though when i played with this snapshot, manager application was available under tomcat ROOT.

this is very frustrating. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There might be few reasons for that:

1. You might be using instance with `LocalSSD` disk. These disks are ephemeral and data is lost on stop/start. If this is the case, take the snapshot of the disk and restore it to new disk which is iether `PD` or `SSD`.
2. Automatic software updates are configured by default on GCE. This can sometimes cause this kind of problems
3. File system corruption. Run `fsck` to check and fix
4. Some sort of backup/disaster-recovery software that went wrong

[1] [Compute Engine Disk Types Reference](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/)

[2] [Operating systems that update automatically on GCE](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/operating-systems/#os_auto_updates)

[3] [fsck reference](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/fsck-command-examples/)

Comment: Thank you DoIT. Gave me some information to look into.
I will try and create another image with your recommendations and see how it handles.